# systemctl stop scripts would not be called when stop scripts failed once using systemctl stop XXX

Tags: centos7, systemctl

I use a squid.service file such as:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/squid/bin/squid start
ExecReload=/usr/local/squid/bin/squid reload
ExecStop=/usr/local/squid/bin/squid stop
KillMode=none
```

'/usr/local/squid /bin/squid' is a shell script with stop function that check squid.conf first before stopping squid.

```
stop) { 
   $SQUID -k check >/dev/null 2>&1            
   RETVAL=$?
   if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] ; then
     do shutdown
   else
     echo "squid.conf is error"
   fi
   return $RETVAL
}
```

we do not stop squid processes directly because of the worry that when squid.conf is correct at first,squid's processes will be running correctly,then we restart squid after modifying the squid.conf with wrong item, if we stop the squid's processes successfully ,starting squid will be failed because of wrong conf.Then the service will be unavailable. But if we check squid.conf first,the processes will not be stopped,so the service is available still.

But in centos7 system,when I do such steps ，something will be wrong：

```
1. systemctl start squid with correct squid.conf , systemctl status squid will be active running;
2. modify squid.conf with wrong, type in 'systemctl stop squid', 'systemctl status squid' will show failed because of stop script checking conf and exiting with code 1;
3. I modify squid.conf correctly again, when I type in  'systemctl stop squid',the stop script will not be invoked at all(I have a test with echoing in stop function,but noting is echoed ). "ExecStop=/usr/local/squid /bin/squid stop" ;
```

so I cannot restart squid if then, how can i enable 'systemctl stop squid' call '/usr/local/squid /bin/squid stop' again in step 3?